# Unable to pass data into Generic DetailView in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to pass two models to my template view. The problem is that no data shows up in the view.

Here is some code that I have tried:

```
 # views.py
 class ServiceDetailView(generic.DetailView):
      model = Service
      template_name = "service_detail.html"

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(ServiceDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           context['prices'] = Price.objects.filter(service__serviceid=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
           return context

 #service_detail.html
 <h5>Other Hospital Descriptions</h5>
       <ul>
       {% for price in prices.price_value.all %}
          <li>price</li>
       {% endfor %}
```

Nothing is passed. Service_id is the primary key and price is linked to the service table.

Comment: Edit the question to include the `Price` model definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already passing prices queryset, then why are using `price_value`? I think this code will work just fine:

```
 <h5>Other Hospital Descriptions</h5>
   <ul>
   {% for price in prices %}
      <li>{{ price }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
```

Or if `Price` model has a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in ForeignKey to `Service` named `price_value`, then the following code will work as well:

```
 <h5>Other Hospital Descriptions</h5>
   <ul>
   {% for price in object.price_value.all %}
      <li>{{ price }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
```

In that case, you don't need to pass the `Price` queryset.

Or if it does not have any related_name, then `{% for price in  object.price_set.all %}` will work as well.

Comment: `<li>price</li>` will literally print "price".  It should be `<li>{{price}}</li>`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yep, Thanks for noticing. I have updated my answer